# Error while attempting to install PyCrypto

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, pip

I am trying to install PyCrypto on Python 36 x64 on windows 10. After issuing the command `pip install pycrypto`, I receive the following:
[the error is here](http://pastebin.com/Tsep3CDw)
I have Visual Studio 2015 with Update 3 installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While ago somebody who knew about the library mailed me and told me that this library is discontinued and is replaced by "pycryptodome".